# How to trigger a Jenkins job in Asp.net with C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, jenkins

i can trigger a jenkins job in asp.net with the following code:

```
protected void submitBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {

          string url = "http://localhost:8080/view/BUILD/job/TESTBUILD/buildWithParameters?token=token123&user=testuser&pass=test&cause=Testmessage";
          HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
          webRequest.Method = "POST";
          HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();
          Response.Redirect(http://localhost:8080, "_blank", "fullscreen=1,menubar=yes,toolbar=yes,scrollbars=yes,status=yes,titlebar=yes");

     }
```

The problem is, that Jenkins does not display the cause after the "Started by remotehost XX:XXXX:XX" message. It has to display it like this: "Started by remotehost XX:XXXX:XX with note: Testmessage"

The cause message is displayed, when i trigger the job with the "curl -X POST" method on a commandline tool.

I think, that something is wrong with my c# code. Can someone check my above code :)

Comment: what is with the extra curly braces?  Did you mean to delete those?

Comment: I have accidentally added an extra curly brace. Thanks i have edited my post now.